# GameMaker corrupted/not opening file unsafe location

Tags: file, file-upload, zip, corruption, game-maker

Whenever I try to open a Gamemaker file I get a warning saying the file is located in an unsafe location and it doesn't upload. If I extract it to a new location it uploads but, whenever I try to send a file to someone even if they extract it to a new location they get the same problem.

Has anyone gone through this and know what to do?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to open one of the automatic backups, they're turned on by default and located under "C:\Users*Username*\Documents\GameMaker\Backups".

[image: Screenshot]